# Error sending to the following VALID addresses Jenkins when Email id is correct?

Tags: jenkins

```
Checking for pre-build
Executing pre-build step
Checking if email needs to be generated
Email was triggered for: Before Build
Sending email for trigger: Before Build
messageContentType = text/html; charset=UTF-8
Request made to attach build log
Adding recipients from project recipient list
Adding recipients from trigger recipient list
Successfully created MimeMessage
Sending email to: chandra.ganpathy@*****.com
Error sending to the following VALID addresses: chandra.ganpathy@*****.com
SendFailedException message: 501 5.1.7 Invalid address
```

This email id is correct which is configured in Editable Email Notification.. Why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 1):

In my case the file size was 5-7MB, it tried to send the file for around 1 minute, but couldn't complete and gave that error message.

Then I tried smaller file, like 10KB, it worked like charm.

So, for my case, my guess is, somehow file is not getting properly uploaded to email server.